# Xcode 4.2 code completion for embedded framework headers?

Tags: cocoa, xcode4

I'm using Xcode 4.2 on Lion.

I have my application project, which I'll call AppProject. AppProject includes a sub project for a shared framework (FrameworkProject). AppProject has FrameworkProject's framework added as a dependency, as a linked framework, and in the copy files (frameworks) build phase.

AppProject compiles fine and I can include the framework headers and classes… everything works as expected.

My questions is about a minor code completion issue: When I type in `"#include <Webkit/"` for example, Xcode brings up a list of WebKit's header files. But if I type in `"#include <FrameworkProject/"` there is no code completion for its headers.

Is there something missing in AppProject or FrameworkProject that prevents the indexing from working? (Once I manually type in the header name, the code completion for that class will work fine.)

Thanks.